# How to apply scope to logs in NServiceBus behaviour middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nservicebus

In the following example, I apply scope on to my ILogger in NServiceBus Behaviour middleware. Unfortunately this scope doesn't persist with the subsequent next() calls. How can I get scope to persist for messages in  IHandleMessages handlers?

```
public override async Task Invoke(ITransportReceiveContext context, Func<Task> next)
{            
    var correlationId = context.Message.Headers[Headers.CorrelationId] ?? context.Message.MessageId;

    using (_logger.BeginScope(correlationId))
    {
        await next().ConfigureAwait(false);                
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something similar to set logging contexts using known headers from incoming messages so that my logs contained contextual information.

There were two steps for it:

1. Handle incoming messages

   - If the message contains the known header then:

     - Store the header as name/value into the pipeline context (or whatever context is relevant for your behavior, assuming that you have access to such a context)
     - Set the relevant context into your logger (I am currently using nLog)
2. Handle outgoing messages

   - Retrieve pipeline context and store it into outgoing message headers

Example:

```
public class IncomingBehavior :  Behavior<IIncomingLogicalMessageContext>
    {
        public override Task Invoke(IIncomingLogicalMessageContext context, Func<Task> next)
        {            
            context.StoreHeaderValueToPipelineContext(KnownHeader.MyHeader);
            NLog.MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Clear();
            context.StoreHeaderToNLogContext(KnownHeader.MyHeader); 
            return next();
        }
    }

public class OutgoingBehavior : Behavior<IOutgoingLogicalMessageContext>
    {
        public override Task Invoke(IOutgoingLogicalMessageContext context, Func<Task> next)
        {
            context.StorePipelineContextToOutgoingMessageHeader(KnownHeader.MyHeader); 
            return next();
        }
    }

public static class IMessageProcessingExtensions
    {
        public static IMessageProcessingContext StoreHeaderValueToPipelineContext(this IMessageProcessingContext context,
            string headerName)
        {
            if (context.MessageHeaders.TryGetValue(headerName, out string headerValue))
            {
                context.Extensions.Set(headerName, headerValue);
            }

            return context;
        }

        public static IOutgoingLogicalMessageContext StorePipelineContextToOutgoingMessageHeader
        (this IOutgoingLogicalMessageContext context,
            string headerName)
        {
            if (context.Extensions.TryGet(headerName, out string headerValue))
            {
                context.Headers[headerName] = headerValue;
            }

            return context;
        }

        public static IMessageProcessingContext StoreHeaderToNLogContext(this IMessageProcessingContext context,
            string headerName)
        {
            if (context.MessageHeaders.TryGetValue(headerName, out string headerValue))
            {
                NLog.MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Set(headerName, headerValue);
            }

            return context;
        }
    }
```